# カラム値が重複していない場合にはその値を、そうでない場合にはnullを返すSQLを作成したい

Tags: sql

内容としてはタイトルで全てですが、うまく表現できていないように思えるため下記に図を記載しました。
一応、実現することはできたのですが、もう少しシンプルに書けるかと思い質問させて頂きました。（case文などは使わず、外部結合を使用できそうな気がしていますが実現できませんでした。）

#### テーブル

```
| name | value |
|------|-------|
|   a  |  a1   |
|   b  |  b1   |
|   c  |  c1   |
|   c  |  c2   |
```

#### 欲しい結果

```
| name | value |
|------|-------|
|   a  |  a1   |
|   b  |  b1   |
|   c  |  null |
|   c  |  null |
```

#### とりあえず作成したSQL

```
select
  h.name
  , case tmp.c 
    when 1 then h.value 
    else null 
    end as value 
from
  hoge as h
  , ( 
    select
      name
      , count(value) c 
    from
      hoge 
    group by
      name
  ) as tmp 
where
  h.name = tmp.name 
order by
  name;
```

#### 再現するためのSQL

```
create table hoge(name varchar(10),value varchar(10));
insert into hoge values('a','a1'),('b','b1'),('c','c1'),('c','c2');
select * from hoge order by name;
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。今回はシンプルであったためpgrhoさんベストアンサーと致しました。sayuri さんも詳細な説明といくつかの手段を提示いただきありがとうございました。

Comment: pgrhoさんの回答は重複行（この場合は２つある`c`）が集約されて１行になってしまいますが、意図通りの結果ですか？

Comment: sayuriさんの仰る通り、質問内「欲しい結果」として記載した条件には2つcがあるように記載しておりました。その点を考えますと、sayuriさんの回答が質問に対する正しい回答だと思います。記載していなかったことで回答者様にはわかるはずはないのですが、最終的にこの結果から重複を除く事を考えておりましたのでやりたい事の実現は可能でした。記載がない条件を含んでしまった質問で申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: 他の閲覧者が混乱するので、質問に合致していない回答に対して承認すべきではないと思います。もちろん本スレッドの内容にとらわれることなく質問者さんのプログラムにおいては適切なコードを採用すればいいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

副問い合わせを使用しなくても`count(value)`自体を`case when`で評価すればいいのでは。

```
select
    name
    , case count(value)
      when 1 then min(value)
      else null end 
from
    hoge 
group by
    name
```

Answer (score 3):

#### 外部結合を使う方法

`GROUP BY`と`HAVING`を使って`name`の重複しないテーブルを作成します。

```
SELECT name, MIN(value) AS value
FROM hoge
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;

| name | value |
|------|-------|
|   a  |  a1   |
|   b  |  b1   |
```

これを利用して元テーブルに左外部結合します。上記結果に含まれない行は`NULL`になります。

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.value
FROM hoge AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, MIN(value) AS value
           FROM hoge
           GROUP BY name
           HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) AS t2
ON t1.name=t2.name
ORDER BY t1.name;

| name | value |
|------|-------|
|   a  |  a1   |
|   b  |  b1   |
|   c  |  NULL |
|   c  |  NULL |
```

---

#### INを使う方法

`GROUP BY`と`HAVING`を使って重複しない`name`だけのテーブルを作成します。

```
SELECT name
FROM hoge
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;

| name |
|------|
|   a  |
|   b  |
```

`IN`を使ってこのテーブルに含まれているかを判定します。

```
SELECT name, CASE WHEN name IN (SELECT name FROM hoge GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*)=1)
             THEN value
             END AS value
FROM hoge
ORDER BY name;

| name | value |
|------|-------|
|   a  |  a1   |
|   b  |  b1   |
|   c  |  NULL |
|   c  |  NULL |
```